# Replacing id's in 2 columns from same table with names from second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am trying to select all Song1 and Song2 rows from my Connections table but instead of showing the id number, I want to use my Songs table to replace the number with the Name of the song

This is the things I have tried and what I got:

```
select Name,Name 
from Connections 
JOIN Songs
ON Songs.SongID = CAST(Connections.Song1 AS varchar)
JOIN Connections as Connections2
ON Songs.SongID = CAST(Connections2.Song2 AS varchar);
```

^ This gives me 2 columns that are the same that only shows song 6 (because it is used in both song1 and song2)

```
select Name from Songs
JOIN Connections
ON Songs.SongID = connections.Song1

select Name from Songs
JOIN Connections
ON Songs.SongID = connections.Song2
```

^ The top one gives the desired outcome for the Song1 Column and the bottom one gives the desired outcome for the Song2 column but I can't figure out how to join them.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and new to SQL

Connections table:

| Song1 | Song2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |

Songs table:

| SongId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Turning Back |
| 2 | Reason |
| 3 | Solar System |
| 4 | Generator |
| 5 | Siren |
| 6 | Circles |
| 7 | Bunker |

The desired output for the first 4 rows would be:

| Song1 | Song2 |
| --- | --- |
| Turning Back | Reason |
| Solar System | Generator |
| Siren | Circles |
| Cirles | Bunker |

Comment: **Consumable** sample data (not images), expected results, *and* your attempts will help us help you.

Comment: I've converted the sample data to tables, have the expected/desired result and put the things I have tried. sorry for not following the guideline, first time posting on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want two joins:

```
select s1.Name, s2.Name 
from connections c join
     songs s1
     on s1.SongID = c.song1 join
     songs s2
     on s2.SongId = c.song2;
```

The following applies to the original question and was apparently *a propos* given the edits.

Your data model and query is a little confusing:

- Why are you converting `song1` to a string?  That should not be necessary.  Columns that link two tables should have the same type -- and be declared as foreign keys.
- Why is a column called `name` stored as a number?

These questions don't need to be answered.  They are just feedback on the design of the data.

Comment: I am getting `invalid column name 'Name'` errors on both `cs.Name` and `cn.Name`

Sorry about the confusion with the tables. I mixed up the names, the top table is the connections table and the bottom table is the songs table. I am fixing it now. This could be why the the query you suggested doesn't work. sorry again

Comment: @BlazeBoss3412 . . . I think the query was correct as you originally stated your question.  I updated the answer to reflect your more sensible data model.

Answer (score 0):

The below query is for MySQL and I am sure this will work in MS SQL too. We are using nested query here, the output of nested query will give SongId to extract the name of the Songs from SongTable.

```
select SongTable.Name from SongTable
where SongId in (select Song1,Song2 from ConnectionTable where ConnectionId="?");
```

Comment: I got an error that "only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

Also will thing query if working correctly give me the whole table or just the one result? Because I need the whole table to be shown